# reading MANIFEST.MF file from jar file using JAVA

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf

Is there any way I can read the content of a jar file. I want to read the manifest file in order to find the creator of the jar file and version. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Next code should help:

```
JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(stream);
Manifest mf = jarStream.getManifest();
```

Exception handling is left for you :)

Comment: uh... what is `stream` here?

Answer (score 47):

I would suggest to make following:

```
Package aPackage = MyClassName.class.getPackage();
String implementationVersion = aPackage.getImplementationVersion();
String implementationVendor = aPackage.getImplementationVendor();
```

Where MyClassName can be any class from your application written by you.

Comment: This is the thing I need (to read `Implementation-Version`). Sadly, this failed to work for me on unpacked classes, though the manifest is in 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'.

Comment: This doesn't work by default unless you add addDefaultImplementationEntries to true for maven-jar-plugin so that it actually has version information in it. By default Manifest file doesn't include anything. Also @Victor, try to run mvn package and see the inside if it has proper information. Generally those version configuration is in maven-jar-plugin or maven-war-plugin, so unpackaged classes doesn't have it.

Answer (score 44):

You could use something like this:

```
public static String getManifestInfo() {
    Enumeration resEnum;
    try {
        resEnum = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);
        while (resEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                URL url = (URL)resEnum.nextElement();
                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                if (is != null) {
                    Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
                    Attributes mainAttribs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                    String version = mainAttribs.getValue("Implementation-Version");
                    if(version != null) {
                        return version;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Silently ignore wrong manifests on classpath?
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // Silently ignore wrong manifests on classpath?
    }
    return null; 
}
```

To get the manifest attributes, you could iterate over the variable "mainAttribs" or directly retrieve your required attribute if you know the key.

This code loops through every jar on the classpath and reads the MANIFEST of each. If you know the name of the jar you may want to only look at the URL if it contains() the name of the jar you are interested in.

Comment: Excellent that this goes through all Manifests.

Comment: I am getting wrong Manifest with this code. It says for example: Main-Class:org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper. But this ist not the case. Strange.

Comment: Iterating over the keys of manifest.getMainAttributes() or manifest.getEntries() give me no keys or values. Accessing the value directly as shown above works fine for me. Is there any background information concerning this behavior?

Answer (score 12):

I implemented an AppVersion class according to some ideas from stackoverflow, here I just share the entire class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AppVersion {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppVersion.class);

  private static String version;

  public static String get() {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(version)) {
      Class<?> clazz = AppVersion.class;
      String className = clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class";
      String classPath = clazz.getResource(className).toString();
      if (!classPath.startsWith("jar")) {
        // Class not from JAR
        String relativePath = clazz.getName().replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class";
        String classFolder = classPath.substring(0, classPath.length() - relativePath.length() - 1);
        String manifestPath = classFolder + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
        log.debug("manifestPath={}", manifestPath);
        version = readVersionFrom(manifestPath);
      } else {
        String manifestPath = classPath.substring(0, classPath.lastIndexOf("!") + 1) + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
        log.debug("manifestPath={}", manifestPath);
        version = readVersionFrom(manifestPath);
      }
    }
    return version;
  }

  private static String readVersionFrom(String manifestPath) {
    Manifest manifest = null;
    try {
      manifest = new Manifest(new URL(manifestPath).openStream());
      Attributes attrs = manifest.getMainAttributes();

      String implementationVersion = attrs.getValue("Implementation-Version");
      implementationVersion = StringUtils.replace(implementationVersion, "-SNAPSHOT", "");
      log.debug("Read Implementation-Version: {}", implementationVersion);

      String implementationBuild = attrs.getValue("Implementation-Build");
      log.debug("Read Implementation-Build: {}", implementationBuild);

      String version = implementationVersion;
      if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(implementationBuild)) {
        version = StringUtils.join(new String[] { implementationVersion, implementationBuild }, '.');
      }
      return version;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return StringUtils.EMPTY;
  }
}
```

Basically, this class can read version information from the manifest of its own JAR file, or the manifest in it's classes folder. And hopefully it works on different platforms, but I only tested it on Mac OS X so far.

I hope this would be useful for someone else.

Comment: The only issue with this is the line containing: String manifestPath = StringUtils.join[...] Using File.separatorChar seems to generate an invalid URL under Windows... probably best to use "/" instead.

Comment: This worked for me, but then I found that the answer by stviper also worked, and was much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Achieve the attributes in this simple way

```
    public static String  getMainClasFromJarFile(String jarFilePath) throws Exception{
    // Path example: "C:\\Users\\GIGABYTE\\.m2\\repository\\domolin\\DeviceTest\\1.0-SNAPSHOT\\DeviceTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar";
    JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarFilePath));
    Manifest mf = jarStream.getManifest();
    Attributes attributes = mf.getMainAttributes();
    // Manifest-Version: 1.0
    // Built-By: GIGABYTE
    // Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
    // Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
    // Main-Class: domolin.devicetest.DeviceTest
    String mainClass = attributes.getValue("Main-Class");
    //String mainClass = attributes.getValue("Created-By");
    //  Output: domolin.devicetest.DeviceTest
    return mainClass;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a utility class [`Manifests`](http://manifests.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.7.5/com/jcabi/manifests/Manifests.html) from [jcabi-manifests](http://manifests.jcabi.com/index.html):

```
final String value = Manifests.read("My-Version");
```

The class will find all `MANIFEST.MF` files available in classpath and read the attribute you're looking for from one of them. Also, read this: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html

Comment: This is great and works well.  Nice that it is a library.  What would make it better is if all Manifests were read.  I notice the Javadoc has an `entry()`, which may be what I've suggested, however that method isn't appearing in the version I'm using (1.1 - the latest at this date on MvnRepository).  The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3777116/1019307 has the solution that worked to retrieve all Manifests.

Answer (score 2):

1. read version;
2. we copied MANIFEST.MF from jar to user home.

```
    public void processManifestFile() {
        String version = this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
        LOG.info("Version: {}", version);
        Path targetFile = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "my-project", "MANIFEST.MF");

        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(url.getFile());
            Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
            try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(targetFile.toFile())) {
                manifest.getMainAttributes().entrySet().stream().forEach( x -> {
                    try {
                        fw.write(x.getKey() + ": " + x.getValue() + "\n");
                        LOG.info("{}: {}", x.getKey(), x.getValue());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        LOG.error("error in write manifest, {}", e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
            LOG.info("Copy MANIFEST.MF to {}", targetFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error in processing MANIFEST.MF file", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. A `JAR` is also a `ZIP` so any `ZIP` code can be used to read the `MAINFEST.MF`:

```
public static String readManifest(String sourceJARFile) throws IOException
{
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(sourceJARFile);
    Enumeration entries = zipFile.entries();

    while (entries.hasMoreElements())
    {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
        if (zipEntry.getName().equals("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"))
        {
            return toString(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry));
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("Manifest not found");
}

private static String toString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString().trim() + System.lineSeparator();
}
```

Despite the flexibility, for just reading data [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777117/3764804) answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one else proposed this solution:

```
File jar = ...;
try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jar)) {
    Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
    // ...
}
```