# maven buildnumber plugin not working with mercurial

Tags: maven, mercurial, build-numbers

I'm trying to get the mercurial revision number in the manifest. I've read following instructions:

http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/add-svn-revision-to-manifest.html

[Maven + Mercurial for Build Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934603/maven-mercurial-for-build-numbers)

I do not get an error message but the SCM-Revision property in the manifest is always empty.

Section from POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hgchangeset</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>                            
                <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

${buildNumber} is for svn. If you use mercurial you need to use ${changeSet} to get the mercurial revision number.