# Inject the Mercurial working directory changeset id such as (838cb9c0367e) into properties file via Maven?

Tags: maven, mercurial, versioning, buildnumber-maven-plugin

We use Maven for our builds and Mercurial for our changesets.  While our software has a major version handled already we would really like to be able to know what Mercurial changeset was used to build any server that runs our software.

Does anybody know of a way in Maven to grab the  working directory's changeset in Mercurial and get it into a properties file or something so we can then display it somewhere in our application when sys admins do a "sanity check" against what  version is currently running?

Comment: Don't know about maven, but current changeset can be retrieved easily with `hg id -i`

Comment: This looks like more or less the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934603/maven-mercurial-for-build-numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merge this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>hgchangeset</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then make a `.properties` file in `src/main/resources` with a property set as `${changeSet}`. For example:

```
revision = ${changeSet}
modificationTime = ${changeSetDate}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could make an update hook which outputs the changeset ID into an unversioned .properties file:

```
[hooks]
update = echo changesetid=$HG_PARENT1 > version.properties
```

Advantage of this approach is that you can easily customize this value if needed, and the build stays independent of the versioning system (or lack thereof).

If you want to put something in the Maven build that generates it instead, have you looked at the [Buildnumber Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) ([hgchangeset](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/hgchangeset-mojo.html) goal) or [Maven Mercurial Build Number Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-mercurial-build-number-plugin/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can intercept command output (into environment variable, f.e) `hg id -i` will be easy way. More complex ids can be constructed with `hg log --template "..." tip`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Maven's antrun plugin to run a `<exec>` or `<java>` task which generates a properties file with that information. That's not very elegant, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/volodya-lombrozo/hg-revision-plugin, if you need more properties, than org.codehaus.mojo.buildnumber-maven-plugin.

```
 <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.volodya-lombrozo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hg-revision-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>
                            scan
                        </goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you can use second properties:

```
hg.author=${hg.author}
hg.branch=${hg.branch}
hg.revision=${hg.rev}
hg.node=${hg.node}
hg.tags=${hg.tags}
hg.desc=${hg.desc}
hg.date=${hg.date}
```