# How to read the MANIFEST.MF file from web folder in Jboss (wildfly)

Tags: java, jboss, manifest, wildfly-8

I need to read the manifest file from java code. The project is a enterprise java project which runs in wildfly. I need to read the manifest file of web. Following is what i tried.

```
  @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

 ServletContext servletContext =
                (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(
                        MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
```

But i get the following error

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/abc.def.rest.ManifestRestService/context -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.abc-ear.abc-web.env."abc.def.ManifestRestService".context
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104) [jboss-as-naming.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:202) [jboss-as-naming.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179) [jboss-as-naming.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
```

Any ideas how to get this working.

Comment: Your `@Resource` injection is failing. Please show the surrounding class declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it is a proper way but I've managed to read manifest like this:

```
@WebListener
public class ManifestReader implements ServletContextListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent evt) {
        ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        ...
    }
}
```

This callback (`contextInitialized`) is called at deployment time.

In our case `ManifestReader` also processes requests (`@Path("/blah")`, `@RequestScoped`), so it has static field where read manifest is stored. If the field is not static, it is null by the time the request is processed.

I myself would like to know better way to do it.

Comment: I tried with success this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700939/2186777