# Get attributes from MANIFEST.MF from WAR-File in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, manifest

I try to get Attributes out of MANIFEST.MF in my war file. I work with Spring-MVC.
I modified the manifest file with the maven war plugin and added build numbers and build date.

Now i want to get those attributes from the manifest file. I searched a lot in the internet and on stackoverflow and found a lot of things. I tried almost everything and nothing works. Thats why i try  to find help here now.

That is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/infos",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getVersion(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String version = "";

    try {
        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(stream);

        Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        version = attributes.getValue("Implementation-Version");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return version;
}
```

The location of my manifest file is the following:   .war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

This is what i get when i look with the debugger in the attributes:

[image]

I get the wrong manifest file but i dont know how to get the right one.
I thought it have something to do with the classloader...

Comment: It looks more like Spring boot than plain spring?

Comment: I added actuator from boot but the project itself is spring mvc plain

Comment: @Hannes :  I'm facing the same issue. Have you got the solution?

Comment: @Ravi : Sorry for the late answer. I got no solution yet.

Comment: I see you have the HttpServletRequest, you are probably in a Controller, you can do something like this:`Resource resourceManifest = new ServletContextResource(req.getSession().getServletContext(), "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
Manifest manifest = new Manifest(resourceManifest.getInputStream());`

Comment: Another useful way, in particular if you don't have the ServletRequest, is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700939/2186777