# Accessing MANIFEST.MF within Java EE deployment unit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to read MANIFEST.MF of my deployment unit which is a WAR file.

A typical way to do:

```
servletContext.getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);
```

But how to do this if you have no reference to a ServletContext? For example in a job triggered by the Java EE TimerService? Or even if the application is not a webapp?

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read the manifest file for a webapp running in apache tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615493/how-do-i-read-the-manifest-file-for-a-webapp-running-in-apache-tomcat)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777055/reading-manifest-mf-file-from-jar-file-using-java

Comment: no it isn't a duplicate. Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getR...() reads from der Classloader Context which is not necessarily the deployment unit one's.

Comment: I have a similar requirement, I am using the Maven (buildnumber-maven-plugin) plugin to create a build id for a server application. I want to access the buildid from the MANIFEST.FM in the main start-up code and log the version, however, this code is running  \@ApplicationScoped i.e. it's not possible to inject a ServletContext because its \@RequestScoped context is not active. I tried loading the MANIFEST.MF via a class loader but that returned a different manifest to the one belonging to my application.