# How to get manifest implementation version from context

Tags: java, maven, servlets, version, vaadin7

I have to fetch implementation version of web application from `manifest.mf` file. I have made the changes in `pom.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
     <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
     <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
    </manifest>
 </archive>
</configuration>
```

I'm fetching implementation version by code

```
String number = VersionInfo.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

But the code returns value null. Problem is **I don't want to fetch this value by reading `manifest.mf` from `META-INF` folder using Stream.**

Is there any way to find this value from Application context?

Comment: There are 2 links help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777055/reading-manifest-mf-file-from-jar-file-using-java. For spring context   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest

Comment: Do you have the <version>fillme</version> tag filled out?

Comment: addDefaultImplementationEntries attribute is adding the implementation version value in manifest.mf ,problem in fetching of value . Why should I add version in pom.xml ?