# Spring boot application.version is null

Tags: properties, spring-boot, version

I'm using spring boot and was trying to retrieve the current application version. (basically the version in the pom.xml)

On the spring boot ref site I can see there is a ${application.version} that is meant to have the version present in the MANIFEST file. (I have checked in the jar, and the I indeed can see this line

```
Implementation-Version: 0.1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

but in the code when I try to retrieve ${application.version} 
(using @Value throws an error saying the prop cannot be found) and using env.getProperty("application.version") returns null.

Is there anything I need to setup in order to be able to use this prop ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the `application.version` property only works in `banner.txt`. I read the `Implementation-Version` from manifest file directly, see [How to read my META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in a Spring Boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293962/how-to-read-my-meta-inf-manifest-mf-file-in-a-spring-boot-app/38005731#38005731)

Answer (score 0):

The application.version is only available when you are run the application as built jar file.  `java -jar springboot.jar`
When running within a editor you will not have the version available.